# extjs4 radar chart bug?

Tags: charts, extjs4

I wrote a demo using the radar chart example in extjs4.1 doc.

And it worked well.

But after I wrote the server-side action for it, the radar chart missed its labels and the radius lines.

Is this a bug of radar chart in extjs4.1?

1. worked well

   ```
   var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
       fields: ['name', 'data1', 'data2'],
       data: [
           { 'name': 'metric one',   'data1': 14, 'data2': 12 },
           { 'name': 'metric two',   'data1': 16, 'data2':  8 },
           { 'name': 'metric three',   'data1': 10, 'data2':  10}
       ]
   });
   ```
2. missed labels and radius lines

   ```
   var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
       fields: ['name', 'data1', 'data2'],
       proxy:{
          type:'ajax',
          url:'radarChart.json'
       },
       autoLoad:true    
   });
   ```

Comment: What does the radarChart.json look like?

Comment: @Alex Hey,the redarChart.json is a http url, and its response like this:[
{ 'name': 'metric one',   'data1': 14, 'data2': 12},
{ 'name': 'metric two',   'data1': 16, 'data2':  8},
{ 'name': 'metric three', 'data1': 14, 'data2':  2}
]

Comment: @Alex I mean that two store get the same data by different ways. One store use local memroy data, while the other one get data from server by ajax request. And the second store making radar chart  miss lables and radius lines.